# common column between combination of one column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-analysis, reshape

I have dataset from my analysis. To interpretate the result, I am trying to build a dataframe

[image: example of dataframe]

Result should be like :

gene_name | Motif_id_1 | Motif_id_2 | Occurence | Matched_sequence

[image: wanted dataframe]

here some motif_id may share gene_name and result should be two combination of motif_id(overlap allowed.)

I have tried following code, however the result does not give combination within motif_id.

```
merge_practice <- reshape2::dcast(group_geneid_CT,
motif_id+ motif_id~gene_name,
value.var ="matched_sequence",
drop = T,fill = 0,
fun.aggregate = length )
```

If possible, I want to make it memory and time efficient and less dependency with packages. Can anyone give me an another perspective?

Comment: Please specify what an occurrence of n and m mean. Do you want to count the number of genes being present in both motifs? So it's co-occurrence?

Comment: @danlooo Yes I want to count the number of genes being presented in both motif. Say moitf_1 and moitf_2 share same genes, however matched sequence can be different, even though same gene. So I wan to save the occurrences between them.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~gene_name, ~motif_id, ~matched_sequence,
  "A", "y1", "ccc",
  "A", "y2", "ccc",
  "A", "y1", "aaa",
  "A", "y2", "aaa",
  "A", "y2", "aat",
)

data %>%
  pull(motif_id) %>%
  unique() %>%
  combn(2) %>%
  t() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  rename(from = V1, to = V2) %>%
  mutate(
    co_occurrence = list(from, to) %>% pmap(~ {
      bind_rows(
        data %>% filter(motif_id == .x) %>% select(-motif_id),
        data %>% filter(motif_id == .y) %>% select(-motif_id)
      ) %>%
        count(gene_name, matched_sequence, name = "co_occurrent")
    })
  ) %>%
  unnest(co_occurrence)
#> Warning: The `x` argument of `as_tibble.matrix()` must have unique column names if `.name_repair` is omitted as of tibble 2.0.0.
#> Using compatibility `.name_repair`.
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   from  to    gene_name matched_sequence co_occurrent
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>                   <int>
#> 1 y1    y2    A         aaa                         2
#> 2 y1    y2    A         aat                         1
#> 3 y1    y2    A         ccc                         2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

`co_occurrent` should be either 2 if it was found in both motifs or 1 if it was only found in one motif.

Comment: first of all thank you for your code. However I just tested with 10 random samples, it returns over 200000 rows. Most of them had 1 co-occurence. As my data is too large and the code will be undesirable for now.

Comment: came to ask for your advise, whether it is possible to average the sequence. Saying from your example, as "y1" and "y2" shares a gene_name "A" but has 3 distinct and different matched_sequence -> would it be nice to average this 3 matched_sequences with generated consensus.