# Edit : combination of one column without overlap and common variable

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, data-analysis, data-manipulation

**Data updated!**

I have a example data set

| Target | Start | sequence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | y1 | ccc |
| A | y2 | cct |
| A | y3 | aag |
| A | y3 | act |
| B | y1 | aaa |
| B | y4 | aat |

and trying to get dataset like in R :

| Target | Start | Start | sequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | y1 | y2 | ccc,cct |
| A | y1 | y3 | ccc,aag,act |
| A | y2 | y3 | cct,aag,act |
| B | y1 | y4 | aaa,aat |

Start column alway has a target and looking for common target from each combination of start column without any overlaps and its list of sequence.
I have tried to manipulate with mutate() and comb() help with following link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71307398/common-column-between-combination-of-one-column?noredirect=1#comment126045519_71307398), however did not achieve wanted result.

Can anyone help me and give me a chance to learn further?

Comment: Should `Target B` be `aaa,aat` in your desired output?

Comment: yes, it was y typo. I edited it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another `tidyverse` approach without the use of `combn()`.

1. `group_by(Target, Start)` so that any sequence with same `Target` and `Start` can be collapsed to a single row
2. Drop the `Start` column in `group_by()`
3. Change the `Start` column into numeric, so that we can directly compare the `Start` values
4. Create a `Start2` column containing `Start` value greater than itself, and extract the corresponding `sequence` string and store in `sequence2` column
5. Expand the dataframe based on `Start2` and `sequence2` (since there would be multiple output per row by `sapply`)
6. `group_by(Target, Start, Start2)` so that we can `paste` `sequence` with `sequence2`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Target, Start) %>% 
  summarize(sequence = paste0(sequence, collapse = ","), .groups = "drop_last") %>% 
  mutate(Start_num = as.numeric(str_extract(Start, "\\d+")),
         Start2 = sapply(Start_num, function(x) Start[which(Start_num > Start_num[x])]),
         sequence2 = sapply(Start_num, function(x) sequence[which(Start_num > Start_num[x])])) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(Start2, sequence2)) %>% 
  group_by(Target, Start, Start2) %>% 
  summarize(sequence = paste0(c(sequence, sequence2), collapse = ","), .groups = "drop")

# A tibble: 4 × 4
  Target Start Start2 sequence   
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <chr>      
1 A      y1    y2     ccc,cct    
2 A      y1    y3     ccc,aag,act
3 A      y2    y3     cct,aag,act
4 B      y1    y4     aaa,aat
```

Comment: if I add a extra sequence with same target and start, but different sequence. By mean, adding case A - y3 - acc can have more than two sequences?

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question to include this scenario (don't forget to include the desired output). I'm not entirely sure what do you mean by "can have more than two sequences?"

Comment: thank you, yeah I should have done it before. I just edited :D

Comment: @berliiiin see my updated answer. I've also improved it to trim away unnecessary codes

Answer (score 2):

You may achieve this by using `combn` for each group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Target) %>%
  summarise(Start = combn(Start, 2, function(x) 
                           list(setNames(x, c('start', 'end')))), 
            Sequence = combn(sequence, 2, toString), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  unnest_wider(Start)

# Target start end   Sequence
#  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>   
#1 A      y1    y2    ccc, cct
#2 A      y1    y3    ccc, aag
#3 A      y2    y3    cct, aag
#4 B      y1    y4    aaa, aat
```

Comment: hello thank you for your answer. With my lack of interpretation skill, can you explain why did you put combn() on sequence column also?

Comment: In `Sequence` column we are combining the `Sequence` value of the corresponding  combination of `Start` values. So in a way, `Sequence` column is also a combination.

Comment: As I might have extra sequence with same target and start, but different sequence. By mean, adding A - y3 - acc does not added to extra sequence value.

Comment: I just updated the data.